# Proving that $|S_8 \cdot a|=\binom{8}{4}\frac{4!}{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

So I came across with the following exercise:

> How many elements are conjugated with $a=(3\ 5\ 1\ 6)$ in $S_8$?

The solution was:

> we are looking for $|Stab(a)|=|\{b\in S_8 : bab^{-1} = a\}|$ meaning $|Stab(a)|=\frac{|S_8|}{|S_8\cdot a|}$ when $|S_8 \cdot a|$ is the size of the conjugacy classes of $a$, meaning $|S_8 \cdot a|=\binom{8}{4}\frac{4!}{4}$. So we get: $|Stab(a)|=\frac{8!}{\binom{8}{4}\frac{4!}{4}}=96$.

I do understand why $|S_8|=8!$ but why $|S_8 \cdot a|=\binom{8}{4}\frac{4!}{4}$?

Comment: @dezdichado So I'm guessing we want to find all the cycles that has size $4$. Do I need combinatorics here? how to count?

Comment: @abuka123 Yes, but only basic combinatorics. The $\binom{8}{4}$ counts size $4$ subsets of $[8]=\{1,2,\cdots,8\}$. The $4!$ then counts the number of ways to order those $4$ elements, but since you're arranging them in a cycle, it doesn't matter which one is first. Any of the $4$ elements can be placed "first" in the cycle, and that determines where the other $3$ go, so you divide by $4$. In combinatorics, we call this a circular permutation.

Comment: @KevinLong Can you verify that my combionric calculation are valid? (link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080909/verifying-the-calculation-if-number-of-conjugate-elements)